# Javascript - Plus sign inside the string of the eval function

Tags: javascript, eval

Look at the following code:

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
{
  deck[j] = eval("card_S" + j + "+1");
}
```

In the eval part, what I need to do is to add one to the variable `j`, but this is not working - I guess the plus sign inside the string has something to do with it.

So how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to use `eval()`? That's usually a sign of bad code.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
    deck[j] = eval("card_S" + (j + 1));
```

I'd suggest that you take another look at your overall problem though, using `eval` for almost anything usually indicates that you have a design problem somewhere.

Comment: @user979830: More specifically, card_S should be an array instead of a bunch of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use eval at all.

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
{
    deck[j] = window["card_S" + (j + 1)];
}
```

Don't use eval at all : Reasoning : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!

Comment: That assigns the `String` into the array, but it looks like the OP wants the actual value referenced by that variable name; see my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt understand the question. Edited.

Comment: Just before I edited, the answer was accepted. @user979830 Can you explain what you wanted exactly?

Comment: i wanted actual value referenced by the variable

Comment: @user979830 In that case, using window[] is the proper way to do it. Don't use eval.

Comment: thank you :), i am an italian language teacher and not a programmer that is why i don't have info about this stuff :)

Comment: If you are going to copy my answer, you could at least up-vote it ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
deck[j]=eval("card_S"+ (j+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval`

Presuming the variables `card_S#`s are in the global scope, you could change your code to:

```
for(var j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
    deck[j] = window["card_S" + (j + 1)];
```